# Summing a dynamic range in a macro. How do I sum a number of rows everytime the name of the customer changes?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 5000 lines of data in an excel spreadsheet and I need to do a repetitive task to the data. I need to put a line break every time the customer name changes, highlight the line in yellow, and sum the dollar amounts. How can I make a macro to add the dollar amounts and move it over one column so I can verify that the data is getting split up correctly at the bottom of the sheet. I'm familiar with macros, but not with ranges that are constantly changing. Too bad the sum function doesn't work in a macro, or does it?

```
Original data

Joes Pizza   10.00
Mikes Pizza  10.00
Mikes Pizza  10.00
Bobs Pizza   10.00
Bobs Pizza   10.00
Bobs Pizza   10.00

Formatted data

Joes Pizza   10.00
Total        10.00

Mikes Pizza  10.00
Mikes Pizza  10.00
Total        20.00

Bobs Pizza   10.00
Bobs Pizza   10.00
Bobs Pizza   10.00
Total        30.00
```

And so on for thousands of lines of data.  I need an excel macro to sum the dollar amounts every time it hits a line break. If putting in the line break when the customer name changes is undoable, at least a formula to make it auto sum the dollar amounts.

This is what I have in the macro and it won't work. 
GetSum
lastrow=thisworkbook.sheets("sheet1").cells(rows.count, 2).end(x1up).row
thisworkbook.sheets("sheet1").range("b"& lastrow+1)=worksheetfunction.sum(thisworkbook.sheets("sheet1").range("b2:b & lastrow))

Can you see an error?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: Could you please at least make screenshots of the source data sheet, and manually populated example sheet as per desired result. If you are not able to post the screenshots, share the links to images.

Comment: Agreed with @omegastripes. You need to provide more information.